# How to reuse SkiaSharp SKBitmap?

Tags: c#, xamarin, skiasharp

I am receiving JPG image as byte array from socket. Then I use `SKBitmap.Decode(byte[]);`. The problem I am facing is memory leak. I assume that decoding makes new instance and copies bytes. Is there a way to reuse same SKBitmap object without creating new one?

Comment: please post the relevant code to show what you are doing and explain why you think it is causing a memory leak

Comment: You can release the previous one, when you start a new one. This can prevent the  memory leak